# Windows 10 retrain existing fingerprint (or, advanced settings?)

Tags: windows-10, authentication, control-panel, fingerprint

I want to retrain a fingerprint on the fingerprint scanner on my Windows 10 laptop, but when I go to **Settings → Sign-In Options → Windows Hello Fingerprint**, the only buttons are **Add Another** and **Remove**, and when I click **Add Another** and scan my finger it complains that that finger was already set up.

Is there a real fingerprint configuration screen somewhere instead of the dumbed-down Windows 10 version, that gives actual, functional management tools for fingerprint control?

It's a Synaptics fingerprint reader device. I'm only using the Windows Hello login, not the Synaptics pre-boot fingerprint feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Fingerprint setup works - I use it here.

Go to Settings, Accounts, Sign-in Options and Remove Fingerprints (remove all Fingerprints).

Now close out, restart the computer, go back and add whatever Fingerprints you wish.

The key is to remove, restart and add.

Comment: So obvious in retrospect, thank you. Didn't need the reboot, either.

Comment: Thanks. True about the Reboot, but I do just for certainty,